# User named [Update Needed] after installing yosemite with encrypted drive

Tags: macos, encryption

I clean installed Yosemite on my macbook air. Everything went ok with the install, and when I restart, there is a second user named `[Update Needed]` . The password for this user is the same password I set for the hard drive encryption. I have tried restarting and this user is still there.

I have logged in with this user and installed all the updates, still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Log in into the Mac as administrator.
- Backup the Mac with Time Machine (optional but recommended)
- Launch System Preferences selecting System Preferences from the Apple menu.
- Click the Security & Privacy preference pane.
- Click the FileVault tab.
- Unlock the pane clicking on the padlock (administrator password required)
- Disable FileVault and wait (…about 3hrs with a 250GB no SSD HD)
- Restart the Mac (optional but recommended)
- Go back the FileVault tab.
- Enable FileVault and wait (…about 7hrs for me!!!)
- Restart the Mac.
  The unknown user account will disappear.
  This should also now allow you to set automatic login.

*Sources:* [FileVault and update needed at the login screen: How to solve](http://www.g8production.com/post/30444154657/filevault-and-update-needed-at-the-login-screen-how-to)
[Fresh install of Yosemite adds [Update Needed] user](http://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/2jxvwy/fresh_install_of_yosemite_adds_update_needed_user/)
[Login screen shows "update needed" but no updates are available](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3321886?tstart=0)

Comment: I think ill just keep that user, it doesn't bother me that much....